# How to bind observable data of service to data binding layout of activity?

Tags: android, android-service, android-databinding

I have a foreground service for downloading files.
I want to have a download activity which shows the current list of downloads with live progress.

I want to use `ObservableInt` for progress of download, and `ViewDataBinding` in the activity.

How should I approach so that I can bind the `ObservableInt` of service to the `ViewDataBinding` in the activity?

I had earlier implemented this by not using `DataBinding` and sending broadcasts using `LocalBroadcastManager` from service and receiving them in the activity and updating the view of the list on each update, but I think that approach was bad for performance, as their were many updates from many downloads every second.